# In react-native 0.60.5, unable to call class function using this from inside render method

Tags: react-native

Unable to call class function using this.func inside render method.

```
type Props = {};


export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  func = () => {
    console.log('hello')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button 
          title='logIn'
          onPress={() => this.func()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

If the func is put inside render method then onPress = {() => func()} works without any issue. Previously this worked in other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your func() method in the constructor itself

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.func = this.func.bind(this);
}
```

you function,

```
func(){
    console.log('hello')
}
```

your button looks like this,

```
<Button 
   title='logIn'
   onPress={this.func}
/>
```

> Since in this way you will not end to create reference each time state
>   changes and when render recalls. Binding the method in constructor
>   itself will help you also in improving performance also.

I hope this helps .... Thanks :)

Comment: thanks it worked, 
Is this a new change in react-native?

Comment: @vishwa it is there from the start. Binding the funtion rather than calling directly will have a huge difference in the performance in both reactjs and react-native. You can read more about this in google. Thanks :)